# what shebang line to use after installing ruby full?

Tags: ruby, linux

I did this in ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
ruby -v
```

which gave the result

```
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

When I write my first ruby script, how do I determine what path I should use for the shebang line?

I tried `#!/usr/bin/ruby1.9.3` but that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can figure out where `ruby` is installed by running `which ruby` and using that path. Or, you can use

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Comment: You mean? ```#!/usr/bin/env ruby```

Comment: @Karsus: I do! Whoops.